# how to compare two complex object without case sensitive in linq

Tags: c#, linq, case-sensitive

I have  to list object. so i need to compare these  object and get satisfied list from "datActualItem" to the list. The list "datActualItem" items may be case sensitive but the list "datFiltItem" items all are small letter my code below.

```
 var datActualItem = (List<UserRoleListViewModel>)TempResult.ToList();
    var datFiltItem = ((List<UserRoleListViewModel>)usersDataSource.Data).ToList();

    var objnewm = new List<UserRoleListViewModel>();
            foreach (var item in datActualItem)
            {
                objnewm.Add(datActualItem.Where(s => s.Equals(datFiltItem)).FirstOrDefault());
            }
```

> Note:- The array list item Firstname is "Sajith" other list is containing "sajith" so currently not checking due to this.
>   I need to checking without case sensitive and  to
>   the add list from the "datActualItem"

[image]
[image]

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To compare 2 lists with custom comparison strategy, you can create a class that implements `IEqualityComparer<T>`:

```
public class MyClassComparer : IEqualityComparer<UserRoleListViewModel>
{
    public bool Equals(UserRoleListViewModel x, UserRoleListViewModel y)
    {
        return x.ID == y.ID
            && x.FirstName.Equals(y.FirstName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            && x.LastName.Equals(y.LastName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
         // continue to add all the properties needed in comparison
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyClass obj)
    {
        StringComparer comparer = StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase;

        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 31 + obj.ID.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 31 + (obj.FirstName == null ? 0 : comparer.GetHashCode(obj.FirstName));
        hash = hash * 31 + (obj.LastName == null ? 0 : comparer.GetHashCode(obj.LastName));
        // continue all fields

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = actual.Except(expected, new MyClassComparer());
```

Another way would be to override equality of your own class `UserRoleListViewModel` but that affects everything and not just this `Except` method.

Comment: You should refine `GetHashCode` method

Comment: @AdilMammadov I was already updating the answer. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @user3185569,Thank you let me check it that

Comment: @user3185569,
var list = actual.Except(expected, new MyClassComparer());

Comment: @user3185569,
in the case below code
var list = actual.Except(expected, new MyClassComparer());
we have single collection of  in the  "expected" list but now i can get all records from the "actual" list. my requirement for eg:
"expected" list have one collection but we have "actual" list have 3 collection. i need to collection only one because "expected" list have one collection

Comment: @Sajith You can use `actual.SelectMany(x=> x).ToList()` to convert a List of Lists to a single List containing all the data.

Comment: @user3185569,
you meant following way

 var list = actual.SelectMany(x => x).ToList().Except(expected, new MyClassComparer()); which is not working

Comment: The implementation of the `GetHashCode` is incompatible with `Equals` and won't work with methods that use hashing. The rule is simple - rather than using special `string.Equals` overloads, pick some string comparer (for instance `StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`) and use it in **both** places.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the valuable note, answer updated.

Comment: @Sajith Please take into consideration the updated answer for correctness.

Comment: @IvanStoev, 
I have updated "GetHashCode" function  like above mentioned. that point of time it is not return any records...

Comment: @Sajith The question is should it? Maybe all records are one and the same (differ just by case)?

Comment: @Sajith `A.Except(B)` returns nothing if all the items of `A` are in `B`

Comment: @IvanStoev,
Yes, All records are same but may be differ just by case

Comment: @Sajith So you want to get the records that are different by case ?

Comment: @user3185569,
I have mentioned  image in the question.
 i have "datActualItem" list and  filtered list as  "datFiltItem ". I need to pick the records from the "datActuaIItem" list based on the matching "datFiltItem " list without checking case sensitive

Comment: @Sajith Then you need to use `A.Intersect(B, new MyClassComparer())` and Not `Except`. This gets results in A that having matching element in B

Comment: @user3185569,

Great buddy....got it my requirement result i am waiting this result thank you..and may god bless you..!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`

```
bool equals = string.Equals("Test", "test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

If you need to use this in `Except` method, you should create class which implements `IEqualityComparer` (see [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx)) and use `string.Equals("Test", "test", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` in that class to compare two complex objects. Becasue Linq does not know according to what you are comparing data.

By default it checks the results of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` (implemented for any object) and the default implementation for a reference type is on the reference itself.

Comment: i need to all satisfied list item to the list so could not working string object. 
so i want to get satisfied collection to the list
var list = datActualItem.Except(datFiltItem);

Comment: why not `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`?

Comment: My code is below how to do this
var datActualItem = (List<UserRoleListViewModel>)TempResult.ToList();
var datFiltItem = ((List<UserRoleListViewModel>)usersDataSource.Data).ToList();
 var list = datActualItem.Except(datFiltItem);

Comment: @Shneeg it is up to your needs

Comment: @Sajith pleese see provided link for implementation of `IEqualityComparer` or have a look at @user3185569 answer for more info.

Comment: I need to all satisfied items to the  list without checking case sensitive

Comment: @AdilMammadov Linq does not check references. Any object has Equals and GetHashcode methods and they are used for the equality check. If it is a reference type then the default implementation is on the reference, if it is a value type then the default implementation is on the value

Comment: @SirRufo, thanks for clarification, but I know that, I said references according to current situation of OP. But anyway, I should have stated it clearly